# OpenGL glGetUniformLocation cannot be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl

I am developing a project using `OpenGL` and I need to use shaders. I have an example project which was given to me but I am struggling to compile it - I get the error: `Function glGetUniformLocation cannot be resolved`.

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04`, and the images below show my current graphics driver and OpenGL version as well as a screenshot of eclipse where you can see the problems list and, as I believe, the prototype of the function in `glew.h` which is included by the project.

[image: graphics driver]
[image: opengl version listed in terminal]
[image: eclipse screenshot]

Comment: Are you actually linking to GLEW, or just including `glew.h`?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I am, in the makefile: `LIBS = -Llib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib  -lCGF -lm -lglut -lglui -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW`

Comment: @HenriqueFerrolho: well, if the linker complains about `glGetUniformLocation`, you are not using glew correctly. The most likely case for this would be you have a file where you use that call without including `glew.h` before.

Comment: @derhass I know that but I am `#include "GL/glew.h"` in the source files where the problems are listed. :/ Oddly enough, the errors are listed only in the Problems tab. Just checked the Console tab for errors and there is none, only a couple of warnings, and the program does run :/

Comment: OK, that is just a problem with your IDE than. It probably does not correctly pare the preprocessor magic GLEW is doing (basically all that gl Functions are macros). That is a somewhat common problem.